# C# Regex Lazy Quantifier not matching expected values

Tags: c#, regex

Using the following input:

```
223.25.99.163</td>
<td ng-bind="proxy.PORT" class="ng-binding">1180</td>
```

This regex is failing to match

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<\/td>.*?(\d{1,5})<\/td>
```

Comment: Change `.*?` to `[\s\S]*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the `.` does not match the newline.

Basically, you have two options: Replace the dot with a even broader match: `[\s\S]` is common:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<\/td>[\s\S]*?(\d{1,5})<\/td>
```

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/sv0k9j/2)

Or you use the singleline/dot-matches-all [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options): `RegexOptions.Singleline`

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/sv0k9j/1)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  Will mark as answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can also insert `singleline`(`dot-all`) modifier `(?s)` to the regex like this.

```
(?s)Your-regex
```

Comment: Love this tip, hadn't seen this one elsewhere.  Cheers Thm Lee.